# Exception Occurred reading CSV file on empty fields

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I am using CSVReader (CsvTools.1.0.10) to read a csv file and then store it in database. I am able to read one file using CSVReader. But I am not able to use same functions on the other file. I checked the file and noticed there were many empty fields. if i remove the fields with empty rows, then it work fine. But since i cannot force user to not upload empty fields file. How can i solve this issue.

Exception: Allow Mismatch is False. Line has incorrect number of parts. Line Number:80; Expected:9; Actual:1

```
DataTable dtable = DataTable.New.ReadCsv(FilePath);
```

Update:
By removing few columns i am able to make it work that means data is too large for a line.

Answer (score 0):

CSVReader (CsvTools.1.0.10) has no way of specifying how to ignore empty fields in the CSV file. Use CsvHelper since you can do that in its configuration properties..

csv.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = true;